# Is there a way to open programmatically a bootstrap model in a textchanged event in asp.net with c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am recently working on a project where I need to open a boostrap modal, but not from a html button nor a asp button, but from a textbox from asp. I have tried a lot of ways, but none of them work, any recommendations about how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.change` event of `textbox` using `jquery` to show `modal` when text changes.

```
$('#yourtextboxid').change(function(){
    $('#yourmodalId').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: oh, I didn't know a function like that existed, but for example if I need to display it, only under a certain condition, be like an invalid password, only when that happens how can I trigger that jQuery?

Comment: You can simply call this `$('#yourmodalId').modal('show');` under whatever condition to show this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.change` event of a `textbox` using `jquery` as follows:

```
//html code for textbox
<input type="text" id="yourTextBox" runat="server"/>    

//jQuery code 
$('#<%= yourTextBox.ClientID %>').change(function(){
  $('#yourModal').modal('show'); 
});
```